# Shift every mode by a constant factor of an audio signal

Tags: software-rec, audio, scientific-linux

Is there any tool for linux which can shift every frequency of the spectrum of a sound signal by a constant factor and output the resulting sound?

Especially I am looking for a way to simulate the Doppler effect for sound wave.

Comment: If you want to simulate the Doppler effect you probably want to change frequency by a constant *factor* (i.e. multiplication, not addition). Probably what you meant, but it never hurts to be explicit.

Comment: Is there also a command line solution such that I can write a simple wrapper script which takes as argument the speed of a moving source?

Comment: You might want to migrate this to http://audio.stackexchange.com as this is on-topic there

Comment: @Rory Alsop Ok, I didn't know audio.stackexchange.com - so you are right. However I don't know how to migrate it, so feel free to do it.

Comment: well - if you get a good answer here I wouldn't bother, but it's worth looking at:-)

Comment: We're supposed to avoid migrating to betas, so I'm going to leave it here since it looks like you got an answer (by the way, you can accept a correct answer by [clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235))

Comment: @'Michael Mrozek'. Ok, I accepted the answer. Now I want additionally a command line solution as commented above. Do you think it would be the right way to post this as new question on audio.stackexchange.com and referencing to this question or would it be more appropriate to ask this as a new question on unix.stackexchange.com since I want a **linux command line** solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/linux)'s effects menu has a [change pitch](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/onlinehelp-1.2/menu_effect.htm) option

Comment: Does this change every frequency by a multiplicative factor or by an additive one?

Comment: Ok, if I use `Percent Change` it seems to be multiplicative! Thanks!